# Make Distraction Free mode show line numbers in Pycharm/Intellij

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, line-numbers

Like the title suggests, when I use Distraction Free mode in PyCharm or Intellij I cannot see the line numbers, even though I have ticked the "line numbers" box in the settings. Is there a way to make the line numbers appear on Distraction Free mode?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) if that helps (I saw a Mac picture where lines were being showed in Distraction Free mode) and my PyCharm version is 2016.2.3.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Showing the line numbers is independently configurable in distraction-free mode and regular mode.

While in distraction-free mode right-click somewhere close to the left-side of the editor window to see a short menu which contains the `Show Line Numbers` option:

[image]

Comment: So simple. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah! Didn't actually use this feature for quite some time (years) until now because was too lazy to figure out how to get line numbers back! #gamechanger #focustime #levelup

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

You can always use the shortcut: `ctrl + shift + A` and type in: "line" and the "show line numbers" option will appear in the list. Navigate to it and press `enter` to turn it on.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me either (it's outdated), yours did.

Comment: For Mac users, `cmd + shft + A`

Comment: You have to **right click on the left side of the editor** to get that menu (Show line numbers). If you click on the middle of the editor it will show different menu. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.

Comment: I can confirm in 2022 that the accepted answer works. There are 2 different menus based on the context of the editor you right-click in. When you click outside the bounds of the editor, the menu containing "line numbers" toggle is there.

Also `cmd + shft + A` works on the mac. Hope that adds clarification.